# How read/edit a .plist file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, plist

I need to make some changes to the file that holds the default homepage for safari, it's on the current location ( in my computer)

```
C:\Users\Sandbox\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\Preferences\com.apple.Safari.plist
```

But i couldn't figure out how to edit this file using c# because i don't know where is the line that it should be edited, when i open the file using Notepad or Dreamweaver or Any text editor, i see the following :

[image]

I'm sure this is the file that hold the preferences, because deleting it will cause the homepage to dissapear, i googled for this problem and i found that .plist is an XML file format which works on MAC.

Now is it possible to edit this file in Windows and from a C# Application in order to set my homepage ?

Comment: I think apple has recently added a binary format plist file. There's a project on google code that handles plist parsing in java, maybe there is a C# version too http://code.google.com/p/plist/.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely not XML anymore, but try that link or Googling plist specifications.

Comment: I am getting the same result as above screenshot. is there any solution for that?